# stop div moving when browser resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using a jQuery fade in/fade out effect with divs, you can see the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EgDqy/13/

My problem is, when I bring them into my main page, whenever the browser is re-sized or made smaller they start to float away from the area where I need them to be and it messes up my layout and design.  Should I wrap them in another div somehow or is there another method to keep them from shifting when the browser is re-sized? As always, thanks to anyone who can supply assistance on  this.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried wrapping the Divs into a wrapper and they still move away from the original area when I re-size the browser.  Sorry if my post was too wordy!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil here you go! http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/chat/index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `align="center"` in html. Use css propery `margin` like this:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Then the block which has such property will be in center of outer block.

Comment: worked liked a charm! thank you so much! you are a life saver.